# Application and driver installation

Tags: installation, installshield

I am making installation project (currently with installshield le that comes with VS2010).

The project contains one file - application .exe file.
and driver files.
The driver files are .inf and .sys that should be installed during the installation process.
there are different .inf and .sys for each OS platform (64/32).

How can i do it with InstallShield LE ? if you plug the usb device you will see it under Device manager and can manually set the driver, but i want to do it automatically during installation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, ISLE doesn't support this.  For a workaround:

1) Checkout how to do it in WiX:

[Drivers Installation With WiX](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44191/Drivers-Installation-With-WiX)

2) Adapt the solution to be encapsulated in a WiX merge module.

3) Add the merge module to your InstallShield LE solution:

[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Certificates](http://blog.iswix.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows_19.html)

If it's going to take you more then a couple days to figure this all out (likely) you might want to just upgrade to IS Professional Edition that has a simple wizard for building an installer that installs a driver.